# MongoDB Reduce Key with single value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I want to count the number of orders by clients, and thus, on the last year, last month and last week.
I wrote a MapReduce program:

```
var mapOrders = function() {
    var v_order = {
        order_date : this.dt_order
        ...
    }; 

     emit(this.clientid, v_order);
};

var reduceOrders = function(p_clientid, p_orders) {
    // Initialization of the output format of the couters
    var r_result = { orders_count : {
        total: {
            1year: 0,
            1month: 0,
            7day: 0
        }
        ...
    }}

    for (var c_order = 0; c_order < p_orders.length; c_order++) {
        // Increment counters
    }

    return (r_result);
};

db.orders.mapReduce(
    mapOrders,
    reduceOrders,
    { 
        out: { merge:  "tmp_orders_indicators" }
    }
)
```

In my output collection, I have 2 types of records

```
{
    "_id" : 80320,
    "value" : {
        "order_date" : ISODate("2015-10-30T11:09:51.000Z")
        ...
    }
}

{
    "_id" : 80306,
    "value" : {
        "orders_count" : {
            "total" : {
                "count_1year" : 18,
                "count_1month" : 6,
                "count_7day" : 1
            }
            ...
        }
}
```

The clients with only 1 order don't go through the reduce function.
I found this in the MongoDB doucmentation that explain that behaviour:

> MongoDB will not call the reduce function for a key that has only a
>   single value.

How can i do to have only 1 type of record in my output collection looking like this? Force all the record to go throught the reduce function?

```
{
    "_id" : 80306,
    "value" : {
        "orders_count" : {
            "total" : {
                "count_1year" : 18,
                "count_1month" : 6,
                "count_7day" : 1
            }
            ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this seamlessly with aggregation. Consider the following pipeline:

```
var dateSevenDaysAgo = new Date();
dateSevenDaysAgo.setDate(dateSevenDaysAgo.getDate()-7);

var dateMonthAgo = new Date();
dateMonthAgo.setMonth(dateMonthAgo.getMonth()-1);

var dateYearAgo = new Date();
dateYearAgo.setFullYear(dateYearAgo.getFullYear()-1);

var pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "$dt_order": { "$gte": dateYearAgo } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$id_client",
            "count_1year": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$gte": [ "$dt_order", dateYearAgo ] }, 
                        1, 0 
                    ]
                }
            },
            "count_1month": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$gte": [ "$dt_order", dateMonthAgo ] }, 
                        1, 0 
                    ]
                }
            },
            "count_7day": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$gte": [ "$dt_order", dateSevenDaysAgo ] }, 
                        1, 0 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { "$out": "tmp_indicators" }
];

db.orders.aggregate(pipeline);
db.tmp_indicators.find();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I first tried using agregation framework but i have to manipulate about 50 000 000 orders. As the $out hasn't a merge option and the max size of a document is 16 mb, I didn't find another solution than MapReduce.

Comment: To allow for the handling of large datasets, use the `allowDiskUse` option to enable aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files.

Comment: Try adding an extra `$match` filter at the beginning of the pipeline to optimize it by reducing the amount of data passing through (aggregating the data you only need, i.e. orders made in the last year up to now).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm currently working with 50 000 000 records which represent only 2 months of data (300 000 000 records / year), so the `$match` will not be my friend in this case.

Comment: I tried using `db.runCommand(
   { aggregate: "orders",
     pipeline: pipeline
     allowDiskUse: true
   }
)` but I laso encounter the 16mb limitation error

Comment: Are your collections sharded?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution using the finalize utility.

```
var mapOrders = function() {
    var v_order = {
        order_date : this.dt_order
        ...
    }; 

     emit(this.clientid, v_order);
};

var reduceOrders = function(p_clientid, p_orders) {
    // Initialization of the output format of the couters
    var r_result = { orders_count : {
        total: {
            1year: 0,
            1month: 0,
            7day: 0
        }
        ...
    }}

    for (var c_order = 0; c_order < p_orders.length; c_order++) {
        // Increment counters
    }

    return (r_result);
};


var finalizeOrders = function(p_clientid, p_ReducedDrders) {

    if (typeof p_ReducedDrders.orders_count === 'undefined' )
        // Initialization of the output format of the couters
        var r_result = { orders_count : {
            total: {
                1year: 0,
                1month: 0,
                7day: 0
            }
        ...
        }}

        // do the same stuff as the for loop in the reducer
    }
    else {
        r_result = p_ReducedDrders
    }

    return (r_result);
};

db.orders.mapReduce(
    mapOrders,
    reduceOrders,
    { 
        out: { merge:  "tmp_orders_indicators" },
        finalize : finalizeOrders
    }
)
```